# Is one hour enough to from Terminal A to terminal B at Newark (EWR)?

Tags: usa, transit, indian-citizens, ewr

I am traveling from Orlando (MCO) to Hyderabad, India. The booking consists of one ticket from Orlando to Newark (EWR), and the other from Newark to India.

I have to change from the terminal A to terminal B at EWR, will 50 minutes be enough to do this?

Do I have to collect baggage and recheck-in at EWR? Is there any immigration and custom procedure while exiting the US?

I am a citizen of India.

Comment: Please [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/152591/edit) your post and do not write in allcaps.  This is considered as shouting and rude.

Comment: You will need to recheck your bags as the first ticket will only get them to EWR, and you will have to check in for the second flight separately, if the two tickets are with one airline there may be a possibility to have the bags checked all the way through. You will need to go through security again if you can not check your bags all the way through, as you will leave the secure area to collect and drop them off.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retrieve your checked baggage, then check it at a different terminal, 50 minutes is not nearly enough time, in my opinion.

50 minutes would be a very dangerous time to allow even without checked bags. Just getting off the first flight could delay you by 10 minutes, depending on where your seat is. Then the second airline will close the airplane doors several minutes before the departure time. Even if the first plane is on time (which is by no means always true) you would find it very difficult.